# Javascript getElementbyId.value not returning any value

Tags: javascript, html, django

I've got a problem with my Django project when implementing Javascript to it.

This is my HTML:

```
<td>
    <h5 id="precioSinEnv">{{total}}</h5>
</td>
```

This is my JS:

```
function calcular() {
    var radios = document.getElementsByName('envio');
    var pTotal = parseInt(document.getElementById('precioSinEnv').value);
    console.log(pTotal)
    if (radios[0].checked) {
        document.getElementById("precioTotal").innerHTML = pTotal + " €";
    }
    if (radios[1].checked) {
        document.getElementById("precioTotal").innerHTML = pTotal + 10 + " €";
    }
    if (radios[2].checked) {
        document.getElementById("precioTotal").innerHTML = pTotal + 4 + " €";
    }
}
```

The main problem is that {{total}} is obtained as a parameter in views.py, and the value shows up in screen, but at the time of parsint it to int, it doesn't work. Any ideas on how to solve it?

Comment: What error are you getting? If you are getting any? What's not working?

Comment: Try `var pTotal = parseInt(document.getElementById('precioSinEnv').innerHTML);`. You're calling `precioSinEnv's` value but not assigning any.

Comment: What is the console.log(pTotal) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change this

```
 var pTotal = parseInt(document.getElementById('precioSinEnv').value);
```

To this

```
 var pTotal = parseInt(document.getElementById('precioSinEnv').textContent);
```

Comment: Further explanation: `h5` is a title element and does not have a `value` attribute (like an input field has, for example)

Comment: @Busto if this answer worked, please mark as the accepted answer so that this question will be resolved. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
 var pTotal = parseInt(document.getElementById('precioSinEnv').innerText.trim());
```